# os.fork() sem_wait: Permission denied

Tags: python, aix

I am trying to compile python 2.5 on AIX 6.1, and the following occurs:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun  3 2010, 11:43:45)
[GCC 4.2.0] on aix6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.fork()
0
sem_wait: Permission denied
741398
```

I have found this bug, which sounds similar:

http://bugs.python.org/issue1234

which suggests setting HAVE_BROKEN_POSIX_SEMAPHORES

I have tried this by modifying the configure script, and I can see it being set, but that does not help..

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

The answer is my stupidity....

From the above it is obvious... The version I am compiling is later in the command search path than another version that was already on the machine....

Rearranging the PATH shows that the HAVE_BROKEN_POSIX_SEMAPHORES flag fixes the problem ...

Duhhh (Time to take a break)